# If P1 is an odd and P2 be an even permutation matrices of size n then, prove that det(2P1-2P2)=0

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-matrices

Statement: If $P_1$ is an odd and $P_2$ be an even permutation matrices of size $n$ then, prove that $\det(2P_1-2P_2)=0$

My approach:
I wrote the term as $2^n \det(P_1-P_2)=0$. Now we need to show that the matrix obtained from $P_1-P_2$ will have at least of its pivot $0$. But I am unable to prove the existence of a zero pivot.

Kindly help me with this proof. If there is any other way to approach the proof apart from the one I mentioned, please do share.

Comment: You might want to have look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: what happens when you multiply P1 and P2 by the column vector $(1,1,\dots,1)^T$?

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!